# Why volume is not changing when app is running background?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

This app is working fine when the app is opened or the app is on the screen. Volume is changing when app activity is opened. But when app is running on background, volume is not changing with slider. If I set the stream to alarm/ringtone, it works fine. But I am facing problem when the stream mode is Music. This code also works on android 11 or less. But it only facing problem with android 12. How can I run the program on android 12?

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) alarm_service.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        set_sound=customView.findViewById(R.id.sound_line);
        set_sound.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                v.vibrate(20);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem. But it seems to happen only on some OnePlus and OPPO devices (with Android 12).